# Differentiable Approximation of the $ {L}_{1} $ Regularization

Tags: optimization, matlab, machine-learning, regularization

In machine learning we are often faced with optimization problems where we want to minimize some energy function using L1 regularization over some of the parameters, e.g.:
$$
E(a,w) = [\text{sum of square errors}]-\lambda||a||_1,
$$
where $a$ and $w$ are vectors of parameters.

If we take the standard L1 norm definition $||a||_1=\sum_i|a_i|$ then the optimization is complicated because this norm is not differentiable.

**Is there a differentiable replacement for the L1 norm?**

Comment: I think you should edit the title to - Approximation of the $ {L}_{1} $ (L1) Norm with Differentiable Function for Least Squares Regularization. It will make easier searching it for later use.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two approximations which are smooth and Lipschitz:

- For every $\epsilon > 0$, $\|x\|_1 \le \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{x_i^2 + \epsilon^2}$, with equality in the limit $\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+$.
- For every $\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_n > 0$, one has $\|x\|_1 \le \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_ix_i^2 + 1/\gamma_i$, with equality if $\gamma_i = 1/|x_i|$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$.

Answer (score 1):

I would disagree with the statement that the optimization is complicated - many pre-existing routines exist to solve $l^1$ regularized least squares.  Just to name one, take a look at [FISTA](http://mechroom.technion.ac.il/~becka/papers/71654.pdf) (or just search for 'iterative shrinkage thresholding').

If you're really looking for something differentiable, just consider

$$
\|a\|_{1+\epsilon} = \left(\sum \vert a_i\vert^{1+\epsilon}\right)^{\frac{1}{1+\epsilon}}
$$  This is a slightly smoothed version of $\|a\|_1$.  This offers no advantage over standard shrinkage methods, though.

Comment: So it means approximating $|x|$ by a smooth function

Comment: There really is no need, though.  Iterative thresholding methods based on the proximal operator work on nonsmooth problems.  Plenty of resources on this out there - for instance Stephen Boyd's CVX package has $l^1$ solvers.

Answer (score 1):

What you're aksing is basically for a smoothed method for $ {L}_{1} $ Norm.

The most common smoothing approximation is done using the [Huber Loss Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss).
Its gradient is known ans replacing the $ {L}_{1} $ with it will result in a smooth objective function which you can apply Gradient Descent on.

Here is a MATLAB code for that (Validated against CVX):

```
function [ vX, mX ] = SolveLsL1Huber( mA, vB, paramLambda, numIterations )
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
%[ vX, mX ] = SolveLsL1Huber( mA, vB, paramLambda, numIterations )
% Solve L1 Regularized Least Squares Using Smoothing (Huber Loss) Method.
% Input:
%   - mA                -   Input Matirx.
%                           The model matrix.
%                           Structure: Matrix (m X n).
%                           Type: 'Single' / 'Double'.
%                           Range: (-inf, inf).
%   - vB                -   input Vector.
%                           The model known data.
%                           Structure: Vector (m X 1).
%                           Type: 'Single' / 'Double'.
%                           Range: (-inf, inf).
%   - paramLambda       -   Parameter Lambda.
%                           The L1 Regularization parameter.
%                           Structure: Scalar.
%                           Type: 'Single' / 'Double'.
%                           Range: (0, inf).
%   - numIterations     -   Number of Iterations.
%                           Number of iterations of the algorithm.
%                           Structure: Scalar.
%                           Type: 'Single' / 'Double'.
%                           Range {1, 2, ...}.
% Output:
%   - vX                -   Output Vector.
%                           Structure: Vector (n X 1).
%                           Type: 'Single' / 'Double'.
%                           Range: (-inf, inf).
% References
%   1.  Huber Loss Wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss.
% Remarks:
%   1.  As the smoothness term approaches zero the Huber Loss better
%       approximate the L1 Norm. Yet the lower the value the harder to
%       solve hence "Warm Start" is used.
% Known Issues:
%   1.  D.
% TODO:
%   1.  Add line search (Backtracking).
% Release Notes:
%   -   1.0.000     25/08/2017
%       *   First realease version.
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %

mAA = mA.' * mA;
vAb = mA.' * vB;
vX  = pinv(mA) * vB; %<! Dealing with "Fat Matrix"

lipConst = norm(mA, 2) ^ 2;%<! Lipschitz Constant;

paramMuBase     = 0.005; %<! Smoothness term in Huber Loss
stepSizeBase    = 1 / lipConst;

mX(:, 1) = vX;

for ii = 2:numIterations

    paramMu     = paramMuBase / log2(ii);
    stepSize    = stepSizeBase / log2(ii);

    vG = (mAA * vX) - vAb + (paramLambda * HuberLossGrad(vX, paramMu));
    vX = vX - (stepSize * vG);

    mX(:, ii) = vX;

end


end


function [ vG ] = HuberLossGrad( vX, paramMu )

vG = ((abs(vX) <= paramMu) .* (vX ./ paramMu)) + ((abs(vX) > paramMu) .* sign(vX));


end
```

The code above matches the form of Linear Least Squares:

$$ \frac{1}{2} \left\| A x - b \right\|_{2}^{2} + \lambda \left\| x \right\|_{2} $$

Yet you can easily adapt it to other forms.

Comment: You are supposed to explain the mathematical idea, not to provide a code

Comment: @reuns, The idea is there by the OP. Give me a differntiable approximation of $ {L}_{1} $. I gave it (No need to rewrite what's on Wikipedia) and showed how to use it. Probably, if was the OP that would be great. I'd like to see it in practice.

Comment: The mathematical idea is to replace $|x_i|$ [by $L_\delta(x_i)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss) and to apply gradient descent to $\|Ax-b\|_2^2 + \sum_i L_\delta(x_i) \approx \|Ax-b\|_2^2 + \|x\|_1$. No need to provide a code. Now the question is what does it change compared to $\frac{d}{dx} |x| = \text{sign}(x)$ ?

Comment: In practice, I compared it to Sub Gradient Method, they have similar performance (Something mentioned in the other answer). The nice property of Huber Loss is it is Lipschitz Continuous. Hence the optimal step size can be inferred analytically as opposed to Sub Gradient Method.